# How to use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table 's TableOperators.Not operator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`'s TableOperators to generate table queries and combining clauses using `TableQuery.CombineFilters`. But I do not see a way to use 'TableOperators.Not' to take negation of a clause. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, these 2 operators like `TableOperators.And` and `TableOperators.Or`, which can be used to concatenate 2 filters. So these 2 operators can be used within `TableQuery.CombineFilters`.

But for `TableOperators.Not`, which is just used for only one filter(take negation of the clause/filter). It cannot be used to concatenate 2 filters. So it cannot be used within `TableQuery.CombineFilters` which needs 2 filters.

If you want to use the `TableOperators.Not`, you should directly use it in the `where` clause, like below:

```
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> myquery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>()
                .Where(TableOperators.Not + "(Email eq 'ivanyang1@hotmail.com')");
```